# Open list of files in default application

Tags: c#, .net

With the Windows File Explorer it is possible to select multiple files (e.g. 5 images). These can then all be opened at once using the context menu. This will open all files in one instance of the default application associated with the file type. For example, images are opened with the Photos app.

I am developing a C# application where images can be selected. Afterwards it should be possible to display the selected images in the default application for images.

Is it possible to open a list of files with the appropriate default application using C#? and how?

So far I have only found ways to open single images with the default application and no way to open multiple images at once as it is possible with the Windows File Explorer.

Comment: What is wrong with looping through the list and opening each image individually?

Comment: When I open the images one by one, each image is opened in a new window/instance. It is no longer possible to navigate through the images in the same window with Forward/Back. Instead you have for example 5 open windows with one picture in each which is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The image viewer installed on a given PC can be either a single document or a multiple document program. Therefore you can't tell if this viewer is even capable of opening multiple documents.
What you want, is to open images (the 2nd, 3rd... image) in an application that already shows the first image. therefore you would have to communicate with an existing process rather than starting a new one - and there's no standard for that.
The only method I can think of would be OLE, as long as the image viewer supports it, but OLE ís pretty old technology and quite complex, so you won't have much fun with it.

Comment: Yes, the target program must support this, but in the case of images that are the main focus, this is usually the case. How solves the Windows File Explorer this Problem then? The Windows File Explorer works this way with a lot of image viewer programs (so there must be a standard way). Even the Windows 10 Pictures UWP App can display the selected images from the Windows File Explorer in one Window (UWP even has native support via the FileActivatedEventArgs so that it is easier to support this than in WPF).

Comment: Please add a little more in detail what Windows Explorer can do. What do you select, which function do you select?

Comment: Open a folder with images in the Windows Explorer and select for example 3 JPEG's. Now you can make a rigth click to open the context menu and click there on open.  (Alternatively you can select the images and press Enter it has the same effect)
The default application opens the images now in a single instance/window.  (If you open the pictures one after the other, each one opens in its own instance/window) The Windows Explorer has to transfer all selected images somehow at once when opening them, otherwise this would not work.